# System.OutOfMemoryExeption C#

Tags: c#

When I'm running my application and load a file(25MB) through it, everything runs just fine.

But when I try loading a file(160MB) I get a `System.OutOfMemoryExeption`.
Although I have been able to load the larger file at some point in time.

Is there anyway to fix this? If so, any help would be much appreciated!

My Code that loads the files:

```
private void openFile (string fileName)
    {
        List<Structs.strValidData> _header1 = new List<Structs.strValidData>();
        List<Structs.strValidData> _header2 = new List<Structs.strValidData>();
        List<Structs.strValidData> _header3 = new List<Structs.strValidData>();
        List<Structs.strValidData> _header4 = new List<Structs.strValidData>();

        var textBoxArray = new[]
                {
                    textBoxResStart_Status1,
                    textBoxResStart_Status2,
                    textBoxResStart_Status3,
                    textBoxResStart_Status4,
                    textBoxResStart_Status5,
                    textBoxResStart_Status6,
                    textBoxResStart_Status7,
                    textBoxResStart_Status8,
                };

        var radioButtonArray = new[]
                {
                    radioButtonResStart_SelectStr1,
                    radioButtonResStart_SelectStr2,
                    radioButtonResStart_SelectStr3,
                    radioButtonResStart_SelectStr4,
                    radioButtonResStart_SelectStr5,
                    radioButtonResStart_SelectStr6,
                    radioButtonResStart_SelectStr7,
                    radioButtonResStart_SelectStr8,
                };

        readCSV read;
        read = new readCSV();

        strInfo = default(Structs.strInfo);
        strData = default(Structs.strData);
        strSetup = default(Structs.strSetup);
        strValidData = new List<Structs.strValidData>();
        readID = default(Structs.ReadID);

        try
        {
            strInfo = read.loadInfo(fileName);
            strData = read.loadData(fileName);
            strSetup = read.loadSetup(fileName);
            readID = read.loadID(fileName);

            strValidData = read.loadValidData(fileName);

            var Str1 = read.loadStr1(fileName);
            var Str235678 = read.loadStr235678(fileName);
            var Str4 = read.loadStr4(fileName);

            foreach (Structs.strValidData items in strValidData)
            {
                if (items.Str1_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str1_headers.Add(items);
                }

                if (items.Str2_ValidData == true ||
                    items.Str3_ValidData == true ||
                    items.Str5_ValidData == true ||
                    items.Str6_ValidData == true ||
                    items.Str7_ValidData == true ||
                    items.Str8_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str235678_headers.Add(items);
                }

                if (items.Str4_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str4_headers.Add(items);
                }
            }

            Str1_data = combineData(Str1, Str1_headers);
            Str4_data = combineData(Str4, Str4_headers);
            var Str235678_CombinedData = combineData(Str235678, Str235678_headers);


            foreach (Structs.strValidData items in Str235678_CombinedData)
            {
                if (items.Str2_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str2_data.Add(items);
                }
                if (items.Str3_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str3_data.Add(items);
                }
                if (items.Str5_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str5_data.Add(items);
                }
                if (items.Str6_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str6_data.Add(items);
                }
                if (items.Str7_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str7_data.Add(items);
                }
                if (items.Str8_ValidData == true)
                {
                    Str8_data.Add(items);
                }

            }

            strInfo = read.loadInfo(openDialog.FileName);
            strData = read.loadData(openDialog.FileName);
            strSetup = read.loadSetup(openDialog.FileName);
            readID = read.loadID(openDialog.FileName);

        }

        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            error.logSystemError(err);
        }
    }
```

Here are the `ReadCSV()` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FileHelpers;
using FileHelpers.Events;

namespace Reading_Files
{


public class readCSV
{

    public int strCnt = 0;
    private readCSVprogressForm _waitForm;

    public List<Structs.strDataImport> copyList(List<strData> copyFrom)
    {
        List<Structs.strDataImport> list = new List<Structs.strDataImport>();

        list.AddRange(copyFrom.Select(s => copyListContents(s)));

        return list;
    }

    public Structs.strDataImport copyListContents(strData copyFrom)
    {
        Structs.strDataImport data = new Structs.strDataImport();
        data.sCD_TimeCP2711 = copyFrom.sCD_TimeCP2711;
        data.sCD_TimeCX9020_1 = copyFrom.sCD_TimeCX9020_1;
        data.sCD_TimeCX9020_2 = copyFrom.sCD_TimeCX9020_2;
        data.rCD_CX9020_1_TimeDiff_DataLow = (Int32)(copyFrom.rCD_CX9020_1_TimeDiff_DataLow);
        data.rCD_CX9020_2_TimeDiff_DataLow = (Int32)(copyFrom.rCD_CX9020_2_TimeDiff_DataLow);
        data.iCD_NumUpper = copyFrom.iCD_NumUpper;
        data.iCD_NumUpper = copyFrom.iCD_NumUpper;
        data.iCD_NumLower = copyFrom.iCD_NumLower;
        data.iCD_NumLower = copyFrom.iCD_NumLower;

        data.bCD_1_Status = copyFrom.bCD_1_Status;
        data.bCD_1_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_1_Overrange;
        data.iCD_1_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_1_Str_ID;
        data.rCD_1_Value = copyFrom.rCD_1_Value;

        data.bCD_2_Status = copyFrom.bCD_2_Status;
        data.bCD_2_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_2_Overrange;
        data.iCD_2_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_2_Str_ID;
        data.rCD_2_Value = copyFrom.rCD_2_Value;

        data.bCD_3_Status = copyFrom.bCD_3_Status;
        data.bCD_3_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_3_Overrange;
        data.iCD_3_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_3_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_3_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_3_RawData;
        data.rCD_3_Value = copyFrom.rCD_3_Value;

        data.bCD_4_Status = copyFrom.bCD_4_Status;
        data.bCD_4_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_4_Overrange;
        data.iCD_4_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_4_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_4_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_4_RawData;
        data.rCD_4_Value = copyFrom.rCD_4_Value;

        data.bCD_5_Status = copyFrom.bCD_5_Status;
        data.bCD_5_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_5_Overrange;
        data.iCD_5_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_5_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_5_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_5_RawData;
        data.rCD_5_Value = copyFrom.rCD_5_Value;

        data.bCD_6_Status = copyFrom.bCD_6_Status;
        data.bCD_6_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_6_Overrange;
        data.iCD_6_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_6_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_6_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_6_RawData;
        data.rCD_6_Value = copyFrom.rCD_6_Value;

        data.bCD_7_Status = copyFrom.bCD_7_Status;
        data.bCD_7_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_7_Overrange;
        data.iCD_7_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_7_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_7_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_7_RawData;
        data.rCD_7_Value = copyFrom.rCD_7_Value;

        data.bCD_8_Status = copyFrom.bCD_8_Status;
        data.bCD_8_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_8_Overrange;
        data.iCD_8_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_8_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_8_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_8_RawData;
        data.rCD_8_Value = copyFrom.rCD_8_Value;

        data.bCD_9_Status = copyFrom.bCD_9_Status;
        data.bCD_9_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_9_Overrange;
        data.iCD_9_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_9_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_9_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_9_RawData;
        data.rCD_9_Value = copyFrom.rCD_9_Value;

        data.bCD_10_Status = copyFrom.bCD_10_Status;
        data.bCD_10_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_10_Overrange;
        data.iCD_10_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_10_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_10_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_10_RawData;
        data.rCD_10_Value = copyFrom.rCD_10_Value;

        data.bCD_11_Status = copyFrom.bCD_11_Status;
        data.bCD_11_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_11_Overrange;
        data.iCD_11_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_11_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_11_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_11_RawData;
        data.rCD_11_Value = copyFrom.rCD_11_Value;

        data.bCD_12_Status = copyFrom.bCD_12_Status;
        data.bCD_12_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_12_Overrange;
        data.iCD_12_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_12_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_12_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_12_RawData;
        data.rCD_12_Value = copyFrom.rCD_12_Value;

        data.bCD_13_Status = copyFrom.bCD_13_Status;
        data.bCD_13_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_13_Overrange;
        data.iCD_13_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_13_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_13_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_13_RawData;
        data.rCD_13_Value = copyFrom.rCD_13_Value;

        data.bCD_14_Status = copyFrom.bCD_14_Status;
        data.bCD_14_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_14_Overrange;
        data.iCD_14_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_14_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_14_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_14_RawData;
        data.rCD_14_Value = copyFrom.rCD_14_Value;

        data.bCD_15_Status = copyFrom.bCD_15_Status;
        data.bCD_15_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_15_Overrange;
        data.iCD_15_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_15_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_15_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_15_RawData;
        data.rCD_15_Value = copyFrom.rCD_15_Value;

        data.bCD_16_Status = copyFrom.bCD_16_Status;
        data.bCD_16_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_16_Overrange;
        data.iCD_16_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_16_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_16_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_16_RawData;
        data.rCD_16_Value = copyFrom.rCD_16_Value;

        data.bCD_17_Status = copyFrom.bCD_17_Status;
        data.bCD_17_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_17_Overrange;
        data.iCD_17_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_17_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_17_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_17_RawData;
        data.rCD_17_Value = copyFrom.rCD_17_Value;

        data.bCD_18_Status = copyFrom.bCD_18_Status;
        data.bCD_18_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_18_Overrange;
        data.iCD_18_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_18_Str_ID;
        data.iCD_18_RawData = copyFrom.iCD_18_RawData;
        data.rCD_18_Value = copyFrom.rCD_18_Value;

        data.bCD_19_Status = copyFrom.bCD_19_Status;
        data.bCD_19_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_19_Overrange;
        data.iCD_19_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_19_Str_ID;
        data.rCD_19_Value = copyFrom.rCD_19_Value;

        data.bCD_20_Status = copyFrom.bCD_20_Status;
        data.bCD_20_Overrange = copyFrom.bCD_20_Overrange;
        data.iCD_20_Str_ID = copyFrom.iCD_20_Str_ID;
        data.rCD_20_Value = copyFrom.rCD_20_Value;

        return data;
    }

    public Structs.ReaStrID load_ID(string FileName)
    {
        var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(strInfo),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strSetup),
                            typeof(strID),
                            typeof(strData));

        engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(strIDSelector);
        var data = engine.ReadFile(FileName);

        Structs.ReaStrID structure = new Structs.ReaStrID();
        foreach (strID filteredData in data)
        {
            structure.steID[0] = filteredData._1_Ste_ID;
            structure.Status[0] = filteredData._1_Status;
            structure.steID[1] = filteredData._2_Ste_ID;
            structure.Status[1] = filteredData._2_Status;
            structure.steID[2] = filteredData._3_Ste_ID;
            structure.Status[2] = filteredData._3_Status;
            structure.steID[3] = filteredData._4_Ste_ID;
            structure.Status[3] = filteredData._4_Status;
            structure.steID[4] = filteredData._5_Ste_ID;
            structure.Status[4] = filteredData._5_Status;
        }

        return structure;
    }

    public Structs.strInfo loadInfo(string FileName)
    {
        var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(strInfo),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strSetup),
                            typeof(strID),
                            typeof(strData));

        engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(strInfoSelector);
        var data = engine.ReadFile(FileName);

        Structs.strInfo structure = new Structs.strInfo();
        foreach (strInfo filteredData in data)
        {
            structure.Date = filteredData.Date;
            structure.Description1 = filteredData.Description1;
            structure.Description2 = filteredData.Description2;
            structure.Description3 = filteredData.Description3;
        }

        return structure;
    }

    public Structs.strData loadData(string FileName)
    {
        var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(strInfo),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strSetup),
                            typeof(strID),
                            typeof(strData));

        engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(strDataSelector);
        var data = engine.ReadFile(FileName);

        Structs.strData structure = new Structs.strData();
        foreach (strData filteredData in data)
        {
            structure.iMDstr_var1_TypeID = filteredData.iMDstr_var1_TypeID;
            structure.rMDstr_var1_Lenght = filteredData.rMDstr_var1_Lenght;
            structure.iMDstr_var2_TypeID = filteredData.iMDstr_var2_TypeID;
            structure.rMDstr_var2_Lenght = filteredData.rMDstr_var2_Lenght;
            structure.iMDstr_var3_TypeID = filteredData.iMDstr_var3_TypeID;
            structure.rMDstr_var3_Lenght = filteredData.rMDstr_var3_Lenght;
            structure.iMDstr_var4_TypeID = filteredData.iMDstr_var4_TypeID;
            structure.rMDstr_var4_Lenght = filteredData.rMDstr_var4_Lenght;

        }

        return structure;
    }

    public Structs.strSetup loadSetup(string FileName)
    {
        var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(strInfo),
                            typeof(strID),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strSetup),
                            typeof(strData));

        engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(strSetupSelector);
        var data = engine.ReadFile(FileName);

        Structs.strSetup structure = new Structs.strSetup();

        foreach (strSetup filteredData in data)
        {
            structure.sSSstr_Sens = filteredData.sSSstr_Sens;
            structure.bSSstr_S1_A = filteredData.bSSstr_S1_A;
            structure.iSSstr_S1_B = filteredData.iSSstr_S1_B;
            structure.sSSstr_S1_C = filteredData.sSSstr_S1_C;
            structure.rSSstr_S1_D = filteredData.rSSstr_S1_D;
            structure.bSSstr_S2_A = filteredData.bSSstr_S2_A;
            structure.iSSstr_S2_B = filteredData.iSSstr_S2_B;
            structure.sSSstr_S2_C = filteredData.sSSstr_S2_C;
            structure.rSSstr_S2_D = filteredData.rSSstr_S2_D;
            structure.bSSstr_S3_A = filteredData.bSSstr_S3_A;
            structure.iSSstr_S3_B = filteredData.iSSstr_S3_B;
            structure.sSSstr_S3_C = filteredData.sSSstr_S3_C;
            structure.iSSstr_S3_D = filteredData.iSSstr_S3_D;
        }
        return structure;
    }

    public List<Structs.str1> load1(string FileName)
    {
        var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(strInfo),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strSetup),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strID),
                            typeof(strValidData),
                            typeof(strStartNum),
                            typeof(str1),
                            typeof(str4));

        engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(str1Selector);
        var data = engine.ReadFile(FileName);

        List<Structs.str1> list = new List<Structs.str1>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (str1 data1 in data)
        {
            Structs.str1 structure = new Structs.str1();
            structure.rGL_1_L_Positive = data1.rGL_1_L_Positive;
            structure.rGL_1_L_Negative = data1.rGL_1_L_Negative;
            structure.rGL_1_R_Positive = data1.rGL_1_R_Positive;
            structure.rGL_1_R_Negative = data1.rGL_1_R_Negative;

            list.Add(structure);
            i++;
        }

        return list;
    }

    public List<Structs.str4> load4(string FileName)
    {
        var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(strInfo),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strSetup),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strValidData),
                            typeof(strStartNum),
                            typeof(str1),
                            typeof(str4));

        engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(str4Selector);
        var data = engine.ReadFile(FileName);

        List<Structs.str4> list = new List<Structs.str4>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (str4 data4 in data)
        {
            Structs.str4 structure = new Structs.str4();

            structure.rGL_4_1 = data4.rGL_4_1;
            structure.rGL_4_2 = data4.rGL_4_2;
            structure.rGL_4_3 = data4.rGL_4_3;
            structure.rGL_4_4 = data4.rGL_4_4;
            structure.rGL_4_5 = data4.rGL_4_5;
            structure.rGL_4_6 = data4.rGL_4_6;
            structure.rGL_4_7 = data4.rGL_4_7;
            structure.rGL_4_8 = data4.rGL_4_8;

            list.Add(structure);
            i++;
        }

        return list;
    }

    public List<Structs.strValidData> loadValidData(string FileName)
    {
        var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(strInfo),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strSetup),
                            typeof(strID),
                            typeof(strData),
                            typeof(strValidData));

        engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(strValidDataSelector);
        var data = engine.ReadFile(FileName);

        List<Structs.strValidData> list = new List<Structs.strValidData>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (strValidData strValidData in data)
        {
            Structs.strValidData structure = new Structs.strValidData();
            structure._name = String.Format("strItem {0}", i + 1);
            structure._index = i;
            structure.str1_ValidData = strValidData.str1_ValidData;
            structure.str2_ValidData = strValidData.str2_ValidData;
            structure.str3_ValidData = strValidData.str3_ValidData;
            structure.str4_ValidData = strValidData.str4_ValidData;
            structure.str5_ValidData = strValidData.str5_ValidData;
            structure.str6_ValidData = strValidData.str6_ValidData;
            structure.str7_ValidData = strValidData.str7_ValidData;
            structure.str8_ValidData = strValidData.str8_ValidData;
            structure.str9_ValidData = strValidData.str9_ValidData;
            list.Add(structure);
            i++;
        }

        return list;
    }

    public List<List<Structs.strDataImport>> loadstrDataAsync(string FileName)
    {
        var engine_Data = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<strData>();
        engine_Data.BeforeReadRecord += BeforeEventAsync;
        engine_Data.AfterReadRecord += AfterEventAsync;

        engine_Data.Progress += ReadProgress;

        List<strData> list = new List<strData>();
        List<List<Structs.strDataImport>> list2D = new List<List<Structs.strDataImport>>();

        using (engine_Data.BeginReadFile(FileName))
        {
            var prevRowNo = 0;
            var j = 0;
            strCnt = 0;
            foreach (strData filteredData in engine_Data)
            {
                if (prevRowNo > filteredData.RowNo)
                {
                    list2D.Add(copyList(list));
                    list.Clear();
                }
                prevRowNo = filteredData.RowNo;
                list.Add(filteredData);
            }
            list2D.Add(copyList(list));

        }

        return list2D;

    }

    private Type strIDSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
    {
        if (recordLine.Length == 0)
            return null;
        if (recordLine.Contains("** #_DATA .STATUS .STRID **"))
            return typeof(strID);
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private Type InfoSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
    {
        if (recordLine.Length == 0)
            return null;
        if (recordLine.Contains("** #_FILE **"))
            return typeof(strInfo);
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private Type strDataSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
    {
        if (recordLine.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (recordLine.Contains("** #_DATA **"))
            return typeof(strData);
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private Type strSetupSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
    {
        if (recordLine.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (recordLine.Contains("** #_SETUP **"))
            return typeof(strSetup);
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private Type strValidDataSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
    {
        if (recordLine.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (recordLine.Contains("** #_VALID_DATA **"))
            return typeof(strValidData);
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private Type StartNumSelector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
    {
        if (recordLine.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (recordLine.Contains("** #_START_NUMBER **"))
            return typeof(strStartNum);
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private Type str1Selector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
    {
        if (recordLine.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (recordLine.Contains("** #_1 **"))
            return typeof(str1);
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private Type str4Selector(MultiRecordEngine engine, string recordLine)
    {
        if (recordLine.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (recordLine.Contains("** #_4 **"))
            return typeof(str4);
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private void BeforeEventAsync(EngineBase engine, BeforeReadEventArgs<strData> e)
    {
        if (e.RecordLine != "")
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(e.RecordLine, 0))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                e.SkipThisRecord = true;
            }
        }

        if (e.RecordLine.Contains("** #_VALID_DATA **;"))
        {
            e.SkipThisRecord = true;
        }




    }

    private void AfterEventAsync(EngineBase engine, AfterReadEventArgs<strData> e)
    {

        if (e.RecordLine.Contains("** #_VALID_DATA **;"))
        {
            e.SkipThisRecord = true;
        }


    }

    private void ReadProgress(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowWaitForm("Opening file." + "\n" + "\n" + "Please wait...", "Open File");
        _waitForm.progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt16(e.Percent);
    }

    public void ShowWaitForm(string message, string caption)
    {
        if (_waitForm != null && !_waitForm.IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _waitForm = new readCSVprogressForm();
        _waitForm.ShowMessage(message); 
        _waitForm.Text = caption;
        _waitForm.TopMost = true;
        _waitForm.Show();
        _waitForm.Refresh();


        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);
        Application.Idle += OnLoaded;

    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Idle -= OnLoaded;
        _waitForm.Close();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What kind of a file are you trying to lad onto memory? What kind of code are you using? Please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: What kind of file? How do you load it? Can you post more code regarding the load?

Comment: That's pretty normal, the longer a .NET process has been running the more its address space gets fragmented.  Running out of nice big holes in which you can shoehorn the data from that big file.  You'll either need to write smarter code that processes the data in the file one record or line at a time.  Or use Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".  You don't prefer it.  Using a memory profiler to keep yourself honest isn't going to hurt you btw.

Comment: @HansPassant doesnt the fragmented address space get somehow compact after garbage collections run?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü - only the managed heap. There's more to a process than just managed memory. (And pinning, among other things, can be an obstacle to compaction so you also need to profile to find if you have those issues)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I would be grateful if you could please tell me about the other resources that the process uses that might be related to out of memory exception, if you have some time

Comment: OutOfMemoryException often occurs if you read a whole file into a `string`, e.g. by loading everything into a `XDocument` instead of using `XMLReader`. string needs to allocate a coherent memory segment without holes. So even if you got 4 Gb of free RAM, you might run into OutOfMemoryException when loading 160 Mb because the available memory is fragmented.

Comment: What does the `readCSV()` method do?

Comment: I'm really concerned by the shear number of methods that all apparently need to be passed the file name. How many times are you actually opening/reading/closing the file over the course of this block of code?

Comment: most likely the main problem here is trying to process large files as a single BLOB/CLOB, instead of processing it iteratively (perhaps per-line in the case of text files); but... we'd need to see some of the actual processing code here...

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier, but I've added the `ReadCSV()` code

Comment: if you save each row in `struct` (my assumption goes from namespace `Structs.`) you have a big problem - structs are saved in thread stack and the size of such stack is only 1 mb

Comment: @DmitryPavliv: "Structs are saved in thread stack" is a myth. They're stored wherever the variable lives. So sure, if you have a variable on the stack, such as an uncaptured local variable, that will have all the data on the stack. But `List<T>` is a class, so *its* variables will be on the heap. All the data will be on the heap regardless of whether `T` is a value type or a reference type. (I see no sign that there's a problem with stack space in the code presented, basically.)

Comment: On the other hand, if these are all structs then the `List<T>` may be trying to allocate a very large contiguous chunk of memory on the heap. Using classes would relieve the requirement for contiguous memory (at the expense of a bit more memory overall to keep the references).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I changed all my `structs` to `classes` and it's working just fine now :)

Comment: If someone of you would **Answer** the question, I could Accept it at an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the comments, it sounds like the problem is really that you're using structs extensively. These should almost certainly be classes for idiomatic C#. See the [design guidelines for more details of how to pick between these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/struct).

At the moment, you're loading all the values in a big `List<T>`. Internally, that has an array - so it's going to be an array of your struct type. That means all the values are required to be in a single contiguous chunk of memory - and it sounds like that chunk can't be allocated.

If you change your data types to classes, then a contiguous chunk of memory will still be required - but only enough to store *references* to the objects you create. You'll end up using slightly more data overall (due to per-object overhead and the references to those objects) but you won't have nearly as strict a requirement on allocating a single big chunk of memory.

That's only *one* reason to use classes here - the reason of "this just isn't a normal use of structs" is a far bigger one, IMO.

As an aside, I'd also *very strongly* recommend that you start following [.NET naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), particularly around the use of capitalization and avoiding underscores to separate words in names. (There are other suggestions for improving the code in the question too, and I'd advise reading them all carefully.)

Comment: Thanks for all your help! :) I'm still learning, so I really appreciate your advice and patience.